# Phinx seeders work in console but not work in unit test

Tags: php, cakephp, slim, phinx

I have a project made with slim, Eloquent and Phinx and I am integrating PHPunit.

Everything works correctly except the new test that I need to perform an information seeder before executing the test.

The seed

```
<?php


use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class Permissions extends AbstractSeed
{
    /**
     * Run Method.
     *
     * Write your database seeder using this method.
     *
     * More information on writing seeders is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/seeding.html
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $data = [
            [
                'id'    => '1',
                'level' => 'admin',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
        ];

        $level = $this->table('users_levels');
        $level->insert($data)
            ->save();

        $data = [
            [
                'users_level_id'    => '1',
                'method' => 'GET',
                'url' => '/api/events/{date:\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}}',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'users_level_id'    => '1',
                'method' => 'POST',
                'url' => '/api/event',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
        ];

        $urls = $this->table('level_urls');
        $urls->insert($data)
            ->save();


    }
}
```

I run it from the console works perfectly,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi> .\vendor\bin\phinx seed:run
Phinx by CakePHP - https://phinx.org. 0.8.1

using config file .\phinx.php
using config parser php
using migration paths
 - C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\database\migrations
using seed paths
 - C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\database\seeds
warning no environment specified, defaulting to: development
using database circe

 == Permissions: seeding
 == Permissions: seeded 0.1773s
```

but when I launch it in the following way for the tests

```
use Phinx\Console\PhinxApplication;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;    
protected function runMigration()
    {
        $app = new PhinxApplication();
        $app->setAutoExit(false);
        $app->doRun(new StringInput("migrate"), new NullOutput());
        $app->doRun(new StringInput("seed:run"), new NullOutput());

    }
```

it returns the following error.

```
14) Tests\Profile\ProfileTest::it_returns_404_status_code_when_profile_is_not_found
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table users_levels has no column named level

C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php:215
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterWrapper.php:191
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\TimedOutputAdapter.php:125
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Table.php:667
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Table.php:610
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Table.php:697
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\database\seeds\Permissions.php:29
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Migration\Manager\Environment.php:156
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Migration\Manager.php:403
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Migration\Manager.php:536
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Console\Command\SeedRun.php:110
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:901
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:262
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Console\PhinxApplication.php:83
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\tests\UseDatabaseTrait.php:19
C:\xampp\htdocs\CirceApi\tests\BaseTestCase.php:44

ERRORS!
Tests: 17, Assertions: 7, Errors: 14.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe the phinx setting file (phinx.php or phinx.yaml) cannot be found. Try to change the directory with `chdir(<your path to phinx.php>);`

Comment: If I quit the seeders the migrations and part of test work correct :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use Phinx\Console\Command\SeedRun;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;


$phinxApplication = new Application();
$phinxApplication->add(new SeedRun());

$phinxSeedRunCommand = $phinxApplication->find('seed:run');
$phinxCommandTester = new CommandTester($phinxSeedRunCommand);
$phinxCommandTester->execute(['command' => $phinxSeedRunCommand->getName()]);

$phinxDisplay = $phinxCommandTester->getDisplay();
$phinxStatusCode = $phinxCommandTester->getStatusCode();
if ($phinxStatusCode > 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Seed:run failed');
}
```